# laravel 5.5 error in routes - InvalidArgumentException Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, kernel

i replace my web.php whit this code, same as my code in laravel 5.2, now im using laravel 5.5, i dont have any errors in 5.2 version.

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
return view('home');
});
Route::get('/register', 'registerController@index');
Route::post('/register', 'registerController@register');
Route::get('/signin', 'signinController@index');
Route::post('/login', 'signinController@login');
Route::get('/logout', ['uses'=>'signinController@logout'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/profile', ['uses'=>'profileController@index'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/updateprofile', ['uses'=>'profileController@updateprofile'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/updateprofile', ['uses'=>'profileController@updateprofilesave'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/updateprofiles', ['uses'=>'profileController@updatechannelart'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/changepassword', ['uses'=>'profileController@indexpassword'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/changepassword', ['uses'=>'profileController@changepassword'])->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/article', 'articleController@index');
Route::get('/searchuser', ['uses'=>'searchController@index']); //Untuk searching user
Route::get('/searchuserpage', ['uses'=>'searchController@searchuser']); //searching user jquery 
Route::get('/photos', ['uses'=>'documentationController@indexphoto'])->middleware('auth');
```

then i try to access url /profile which means need authenticate first, and it show me an error `InvalidArgumentException Route [login] not defined.` how to solve this problem. thankyou

this is my code for Authenticate.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::Check()){
        return $next($request);
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/signin');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call a route in your project you must define **route name** .

such as :

```
<form action:"{{route('login')}}" method="post">
```

and in route :

```
Route::post('/signin', 'signinController@index')->name('login')
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from the fact that somewhere in your code upon instantiation you're referring to a named route called 'login' but it's not defined in your web.php file.

An example of hitting this issue is you may have a redirect pointing to this route somewhere tucked away in one of your controllers, for example:

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

To fix this issue, apply the name to the applicable route.

```
Route::post('/login', 'signinController@login')->name('login');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with the named routes. Please make sure which all places the named routes is being used.

```
Route::get('/signin', 'signinController@index')->name('login')
```

Here, you can see I named this route `login` and I can call this route anywhere using `route('login')` helper method.